# Additively updating model parameters (not fine-tuning) in DNNs and XGBoost

Tags: python, deep-learning, xgboost, pre-trained-model

I need a regression model to train on tabular data daily, that cannot take more than 5 minutes to train during the week, but can take up to an hour at the weekend. Hardware upgrades are out of scope of this question.

So far my two options have been:

- A simple linear model that trains quickly, but has less skill
- Training a DNN at the weekend, and then running an update cycle every day during the week, where model weights from the pretrained model (from the weekend) are updated on the last few days (with the same verification set as the weekend model, but much smaller training data). Tests have shown this to give better results than just training once a week.

Question 1) - Is the DNN update method accepted practice? I can't find many examples of additive model updates online (vs. fine-tuning, where the new data is used to change the scope of the model, rather than simply adding to it with a validation set drawn from the same data).
Question 2) - I would like to try something similar to the DNN update method with XGBoost, but cannot find a way to update a model once it has already been trained?